# How to set the distance between soft vertical lines on a Seaborn graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am making a line graph with Seaborn and want to have more tick lines on my graph than x-axis ticks written at the bottom of the graph but am unsure how to do it. I want to keep the x-axis labels to only include years but have a tick line for every 4 months. Is this possible using Seaborn and how would I go about doing this if it is?

To get the x-axis values, I have a data column in the format `%Y/%m/01` and my [current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wXcp.png) has a tick line for every year.

I tried using the x-axis formatting APIs of Seaborn and matplotlib but these all adjust the x-axis labels as well whereas I want to keep labels for only years but have tick lines every 4 months.

Comment: Have you looked into Matplotlib's major and minor tick locator?

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about that API.

I was able to get the ticks with `ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonth=[1, 4, 7, 10], bymonthday=1))` to show minor ticks every 4 months and `plt.grid(which='minor')` to show the minor ticks on the grid. Do you know if there is a way to format the ticks differently?